# Incorrect placement of diacritics in Arabic fonts

Tags: unity, text, fonts

I put AdobeNaskh font on my texts and use Arabic text support for unity and use show Tashkeel function then the text appears so [image: text]

what is the solution of this problem?

[image: text with correct diacritics but not the same font]